# Node / Express.js api run request via terminal

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node.js / express server where I get information by adding requests on my browser like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/list/1
```

This will return me a list of data.

My question is...Is there anyway where I can open a terminal window and make the same request from there?

Can this be done, if so how?

Here's the route code:

```
app.route('/list/:id')
  .get((req:Request, res: Response) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    res.status(200).send(list[id]);
});
```

Comment: Sure, you could make an HTTP request from terminal using curl (as linked in above comment) or you could run your node server directly from terminal and pass in commands to it. For example, you could have a script that runs the same Express route that you run at `list/1` and returns the output directly to terminal. Which route are you interested in? If the latter, paste some code from your Express setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think about using [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (Postman is not running in a terminal, but worth a look at). With curl you would do `curl http://localhost:3000/list/1` for a simple `GET`-request.

Let's assume you have the following *index.js* running with `node ./index.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'foo' });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Then, `curl localhost:3000/foo` prints `{"name":"foo"}`.

Comment: t's displaying a lot of stuff ... I just want it to return the content value. How can I do that? I am getting the Content but also StatusCode, StatusDescription etc I only want to Content value

Comment: This is from server.ts: import app from "./app";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('listening on port ' + PORT);
})

Comment: Can you post your code where you add the route for `http://localhost:3000/list/1` and where you create its respond? And please post is within your question :)

Comment: Try `res.status(200).json(list[id]);` if you want your response as JSON. If this does not work, post your curl command and its output.

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned you can use curl or also create a CLI in node.js where you can interact with your server data:
Kindly, let me share you a CLI code made using nodeJS inorder that you have a better idea how you can do this:
https://github.com/eum602/NodeJSMasterClass_4_PizzaDelivery/blob/master/lib/cli.js